# How to count and check if cells are true or false for some condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I have to check for all cells from A0 to A10 if the value of cell is smaller then 100 and if it is increase value of B0 to +1. I'am complete noob for excel and I have test tomorrow. Please help, what function can do that.
I need my program to do this but in excel:

```
int variable = 0;
if (cell(A0:A10)<100) variable++;
```

And how to print "yes" if if-function that checks value of cell is true or false and then print "no"

Comment: cells `A0` and `B0`??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will do this, in column A1 (A0 doesn't exist) will add this formula:
    =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,"yes")
which will count how many cells are below 100.

And then, next to the value from A2 to A10, beginning in column B2, I will add:
    =IF(A2<100,"yes","no")
which determined if value is less than 100, then "yes".